# How do I create a account_id-user_id mapping df based on a account_id-date-cluster_id mapping df (Pyspark)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a mapping table (account_id - date - cluster_id)

Example:

| account_id | date | cluster_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | A |
| 2 | 2018 | A |
| 2 | 2019 | B |
| 3 | 2019 | B |
| 1 | 2020 | C |
| 4 | 2020 | C |
| 1 | 2021 | D |
| 5 | 2021 | A |

Rules:

- The same cluster_id means it is the same user, but only for a specific date. So a single account could have multiple cluster_ids on different dates
- A cluster_id for a specific date could have multiple account_ids
- A single cluster_id could appear on multiple dates and not necessarily mean they are the same user

Using this table, I want to create a account_id - user_id mapping.

Expected Output:

| account_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |

** the actual user_id isn't important, as long as the correct accounts are linked together

I tried this to start, but don't think it's correct. Open to any ideas you have.

```
df_user_mapping = cluster_df.withColumn('intermediate_group_id', F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('year','month','cluster_id')).selectExpr('account_id','month','year','cluster_id as group_id','intermediate_group_id')
inter_groups = df_user_mapping.groupBy('account_id').agg(F.collect_set('intermediate_group_id').alias('intermediate_groups')))
groups = df_user_mapping.groupBy('account_id','year','month').agg(F.collect_set('group_id').alias('groups')))
joined = groups.join(inter_groups, ['account_id'], 'outer')
inter_explode = joined.select('account_id','groups','year','month',F.explode('intermediate_groups').alias('intermediate_group_id'))
group_explode = inter_explode.select('account_id','intermediate_group_id','year','month',F.explode('groups').alias('group_id'))
first_ids = group_explode.withColumn('first_id_inter', F.min('account_id').over(Window.partitionBy('inter_group_id'))).withColumn('first_id_group', F.min('first_id_inter').over(Window.partitionBy('group_id','year','month'))).withColumn('first_id', F.min('first_id_group').over(Window.partitionBy('account_id')))
final = first_ids.selectExpr('account_id','first_id as user_id').distinct()
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts at all!

Starter template

```
example = [('1',1,2018,'A'),
           ('2',1,2018,'A'),
           ('2',1,2019,'B'),
           ('3',1,2019,'B'),
           ('1',1,2020,'C'),
           ('4',1,2020,'C'),
           ('1',1,2021,'D'),
           ('5',1,2021,'A'),
          ]
example_df = spark.createDataFrame(example, ['account_id','month','year','cluster_id'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank, collect_set, explode

# Step 1: Create a new column 'user_id' and set it to 0 for all rows
df = df.withColumn('user_id', F.lit(0))

# Step 2: Loop through the dataframe, grouping by cluster_id and date
# and assigning unique user_ids to each group
counter = 1
for name, group in df.groupby(['cluster_id', 'date']):
    df = df.withColumn('user_id', F.when((df['cluster_id'] == name[0]) & (df['date'] == name[1]), counter).otherwise(df['user_id']))
    counter += 1

# Step 3: Sort the dataframe by account_id and date
df = df.sort(['account_id', 'date'])

# Step 4: Loop through the sorted dataframe and assign the user_id of the first row
# to all subsequent rows for the same account_id
current_account_id = None
current_user_id = None
for row in df.collect():
    if row['account_id'] != current_account_id:
        current_account_id = row['account_id']
        current_user_id = row['user_id']
    else:
        df = df.withColumn('user_id', F.when(df['account_id'] == current_account_id, current_user_id).otherwise(df['user_id']))

# The resulting dataframe should have the desired account_id - user_id mapping
df.show()
```

Comment: Step 2, I believe the "for nam.." line should be "df.toPandas.groupby".. fails otherwise

Still, the result I'm getting doesn't match the expected output. For instancee, panelist_id 3 is assigned user_id 3 when it should be 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).